# Unable to register silverlight user control in aspx page

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have made a simple silverlight application. Everything is working fine but I am unable to use silverlight user control as my aspx page shows only embedded object code.

I have also tried to register the silverlight control with the following code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.SilverLight"  Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverLightControls" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

but it did not work. I want to do this, so that I would able to pass parameter to silverlight control from my aspx page.

How should I register the silverlight user control in my aspx page? I am using silverlight 3.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

The Silverlight server control is no longer supported in version 3.0.  You will need to use the object html tag instead.  See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188746/silverlight-3-tools-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio/1188761#1188761).